# Can't log onto drupal with any email address

Tags: users

I am receiving "Account Approval" spam at one of my email addresses. I can't log onto to Drupal using that or any other email address I am using. When requesting new password using various email addresses, all are rejected as unknown. Will creating a new account allow me to install module(s) to kill spam?

Comment: Use the super-admin account (the user account created when the site was installed initially) to login and do that. If you just create a new account on the front end, it will most likely have only low level permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider editing the eMailId currently stored in the Drupal database, using PhpMyAdmin. And this by replacing that eMail ID with some other eMail ID that is usable for you.

Then use the "request new pasword" feature for that account, which should be mailed now to the eMail Id that you can work with. Use the password reset link and you should be up and running.

Does this help?